# What is the correct way to setup "Pretty" permalinks in Wordpress 3.0

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I'm been trying to figure this one out for ages but I can't seem to do it. I have an ubuntu 10.04 server with wordpress installed on it. I am trying to make my wordpress use "Pretty" permalinks however every time I try it doesn't seem to work.

This is my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file is owned by root and it is chmod to 644 (security reasons) and it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Suggestions and a solution would be most welcomed

Comment: Is mod_rewrite module enabled in Ubuntu?

Comment: for the love of ##### ... yes typical me, mod_rewrite was not enabled and that solved my problem. If anyone else has this problem I enabled it by using sudo a2enmod rewrite